# undoing armature skinning?

Tags: armature

I want to undo armature skinning I pressed ctrl z but didnt work since the file was saved and opened again so I think I lost the reversing by ctrl z function [image]

Answer (score 2):

To remove all armature influence, you will need to remove the parent and remove the armature modifier from the mesh.

Select the mesh object and press <kbd>ALT-P</kbd> -> Clear Parent to remove parenting. Go to the modifier properties and remove all armature modifiers with the X on the right. Do not apply the modifier nor apply it as a shapekey.

[image: Armature modifier]